# AES encryption for iOS and Android

Tags: android, iphone

We are creating same project in android and iPhone. Now the problem is that we need to send some information to php server using web service in aes encrypted form. We both have implemented it but results are different so is there a common AES encryption method which will produce same result and can be parsed at the php server.

Comment: Provide more information (encryption modes, padding, etc) as well as actual source code for all three platforms to get an useful answer. Hint: all the downvotes mean that this is not a well formulated question.

Comment: Hey there have a look at this, there my colleague and me posted the correct way how to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535918/aes-gets-different-results-in-ios-and-java/19219704#19219704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using the exact same AES mode?
I would suggest checking that. (For example maybe in the one you are using Padding and in the other one not, or the one is in [CBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) mode whereas the other is not)